# Upper bound for $|\int_\gamma f(z)e^{iz} dz |$

Tags: contour-integration

> Let $\Omega = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} | Im(z) > 0 \}$ and $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function.
>
> We suppose that $\forall z \in \Omega : |f(z)| \leq M|z|^n$
>
> We define $\gamma : [0,\pi] \to \mathbb{C}$ by $\gamma (t) = Re^{it}$
>   with $R >0$.
>
> We want to prove that $|\int_\gamma f(z)e^{iz} dz | \leq M \pi R^n$

I think I managed to prove $|\int_\gamma f(z)e^{iz} dz | \leq M \pi R^{n+1}$ using obvious inequalities. So I got $R^{n+1}$ and not $R^n$.

Can someone tell wich one is true ?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568246/question-regarding-integral-of-the-form-oint-limits-s-rei-cdot-k-cdot-z) for a proof of the bound $M\pi R^n$.

Comment: Thank you. But then, what's wrong with @guestDiego answer (in this topic) ?

Comment: He apparently thought $\lvert e^{-iz}\rvert  = 1$, but $\lvert e^{-iz}\rvert = e^{\operatorname{Im} z}$, and that is large in the upper half-plane, at $z = iR$, we have $e^{-i(iR)} = e^R$.